# Angularjs & Java Servlet: How do i retrieve object being pass from angular service to java servlet

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

Hi guys i am integrating an angularjs and java for the first time but i do have wide experience in angularjs. my question is how do i retrieve object being pass to a java servlet.

i pass the data using angularjs service

```
    function validateUser(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.POST('api/user', data)
        .then(function(response) {
            defer.resolve(response);
        }).catch(function(response) {
            defer.reject(response);
        })          
        return defer.promise;           
    }
```

and my java servlet API:

```
@WebServlet("/api/user")
public class UserController extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public UserController() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //store request body

}
```

}

my goal here is to get the whole object not just the parameter if its possible. thank u in advance

Comment: What about `req.getParameter("parameterName")`? See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String) or https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()

Comment: thnx for the docs. but "req.getParament("parameterName")" is not useful since i am passing an object.

Comment: Nope. You are not passing an object. For a simple servlet (i.e. without using a framework), everything passed in a request is a `String` (except for uploading a file, but that's not your case). So you are sending your JS object, but according to [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#default-transformations), this object is serialized as JSON string - and your servlet has to retrieve it as such, and deserialize it. It's your responsibility.